# How to get the Record id of a pageblocktable individual row?

Tags: visualforce

I am displaying a list of all Case records in a pageblocktable. The Case object has a relationship to Asset. On click of a related field (Asset), I want to get the record details. How to do this?

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!openList}" var="a" id="theTable1" styleClass="mytable" > 
    <apex:column value="{!a.CaseNumber}" headerValue="CaseNumber"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!a.Reason}" headerValue="Reason"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!a.Status}" headerValue="Status"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!a.Service_For__c}" headerValue="Service For"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!a.Assigned_To__c}" headerValue="Assigned To"/> 
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Post your code. That would be more helpful

Comment: What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. As written, this question more or less reads like a request for the community to do your work for you. Also, are you trying to get this information in Javascript? How do you intend to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <apex:column headerValue="CaseNumber">
    <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Asset.View, a.id)}">{!a.CaseNumber}</apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
```

If you want to redirect to asset view page, above code may work.

Comment: I don't want to redirect to Asset view page. I want to get the record Id for other manipulation. How do to this?